# How to ensure that maven doesn't accidentally deploy to release repoisitory?

Tags: maven, artifactory, maven-plugin, mvn-repo

So I'm working for a customer that uses mvn deploy statements in his build scripts and I'm trying to figure out a way to prevent maven to accidentally overwrite artifacts in the release repo of Artifactory, for instance if a developer forgets to mark his POM version with -SNAPSHOT on his feature branch.

I'm no maven expert, but I've seen some suggestions, like using certain maven plugins, but these plugins' usage must be configured in the POM and then I'm back where I started, what if this is forgotten on a feature branch? There must be an established method to ensure that no artifacts from feature branches are deployed into the release repo and that no artifacts from release branches are deployed into the snapshot repo by accident.

One way I can think of and that also has been suggested is, to simply disallow redeployment on the release repo in Artifactory, but what if I have a validation build that fires after a PR is created and then another CI build fires and tries to redeploy?

Is there another good way to achieve this?

Comment: The redeployment for releases repos should always being prevent because releases are immutable. Why need to change to `-SNAPSHOT` in a feature branch? The `main` branch should already be `-SNAPSHOT` so each feature branch has already `-SNAPSHOT` on it... The release should be triggered via Jenkins which changes the version into non SNAPSHOT`s... that would solve the problem...

Comment: OK, I'm confused, again I don't usually work with maven. Do you know of any good resource where this whole workflow is described?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to ensure specific users/groups do **not** have the Delete permission.

See more here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions#Permissions-RepositoryPermissions.

NOTE: I haven't used Artifactory in a while, but this makes sense according to the docs.

Comment: yes, we have this mechanism as well, but that does only affect actual users, not the account under which I'm running the build system. This account should have overwrite permissions

Comment: Another solution is to have suffixes added to releases for duplicates, e.g., `-X`. The repo will just point to the latest, or you can specify the suffix is the version. I know this is possible because we did it at a past position, but forget how to accomplish it.

Comment: In lieu of a solution in my last comment, you could always add a timestamp to the artifact like `<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>`. You could also use `buildnumber-maven-plugin` to create a property with a number.

Comment: I will checkout the buildnumber-maven-plugin, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know how it works, either with a check or a comment if you need more assistance!